# How to send Breezingforms (WordPress version) via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, breezingforms

I took on some sites that use Breezing Forms (https://wordpress.org/plugins/breezing-forms/). The plugin is pretty trash but these websites have some major forms built using it.

I need to hook onto an an ajaxComplete event using it, but I see no settings for submitting via AJAX.

Anyone know how I could accomplish this?